# How to get categories by custom field?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WP plugin "Advance custom field" and I'm interested is it possible to get categories (custom query or some wp query) over custom field.

For example I've created field "Show on Home page?" (radio button which has values: Yes or NO).

Can I get categories by this custom field (if Yes is selected) ?
Thank you

UPDATE:

```
$categories = get_categories( $args );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use get_option(). Like this:

```
$term_options = get_option( "taxonomy_{$term_id}" );
echo $term_options['show_on_home_page'];
```

**EDIT:**
If you don't know how to get the term_id, it's accessible in the category object.

```
$categories = get_categories( array (....) );
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
   $term_options = get_option( "taxonomy_{$category->term_id}" );
   echo $term_options['show_on_home_page']; 
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
I understand that you only want to get categories by that custom field. To do that you need to do a custom query because there's no such built in function in Wordpress. That is a bit complicated. I'm sure [get_terms()](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1187) can help you get the query right, then you just need to join the options table (wp_options) and what you need here is option_name wich you need to do a [concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) so you can get taxonomy_354. The value for the option is a object that looks like this:

```
a:1:{s:3:"show_on_home_page";s:12:"yes";}
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT3:**
Use concat() like this in your query `CONCAT('taxonomy_', terms.term_id)`

Comment: this mean that I must list all my categories and then get home categories. For example lets say that I have 100 categories. Thats 1 main query over which I get all categories and 100 subqueries over which I found out if it is home category or no. That's not good :(

Comment: Yes I just noticed, I misread the question. I will update my answer.

Comment: Can you give me please link to documentation of "concat()"?

Comment: No problem, just glad to be able to help :)